# Permission denied (publickey,password) Apache in Ubuntu 20.04LTS

Tags: server, permissions, ssh, apache2, django

I obtain the above mentioned error "Permission denied (publickey,password)" when trying to connect with ssh using my apache server. The framework I have used is Django and when deploying it locally (with python) the ssh communication works perfectly. However, when I deploy it with apache on every ssh, scp communication I obtain the error.

This is what I have tried so far:

1. Proper ssh key. It asks me for the passphrase the first time I connect via terminal or with the py deployment server
2. Permission of `~/.ssh` folder is 700, `~/.ssh/id_rsa` is 600, and `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` is 644
3. I have changed both the owner of the key to www-data and the user of apache to my sudo
4. Disabled password authentication on the server

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Use `ssh -v` or even `ssh -v -v` to get more details of the failing login procedure.

Comment: Thanks. I tried and what I obtained is `debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such device or address`. I was thinking that client is unable to open a terminal device to read the passphrase for the private key, therefore I added the key manually by  `eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
ssh-add /path/to/private_key`, but the problem still persists. Do you know if there is any way to run this command alongside Apache?

Comment: See [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/251876/debug1-read-passphrase-cant-open-dev-tty-no-such-device-or-address-when-t). What does `ls -la /dev/tty` show?

Comment: According to the post above mentioned, I obtain the correct permissions `crw-rw-rw- 1 root tty 5, 0 Feb 14 09:35 /dev/tty`. I have even changed the owner of the `tty` folder from `root` to the apache service `www-data`, and still not working